# Execute SQL Procedure in Oracle Database with batch file

Tags: batch-file, oracle11g, sqlplus

I created a .bat file to execute procedure with these lines:

```
echo off
sqlplus username/password@databasename
set heading off
set feedback off
BEGIN
AML.DO_ACCOUNT_AML() ;
COMMIT

END;
/
exit;
!
```

. It could only connect to database but couldn't execute query.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps (as you were already told): batch script + SQL script.

**Batch script**

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @run_proc.sql
```

**SQL script (run_proc.sql)**

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  p_test;
end;
/
exit
```

**Stored procedure**

```
create or replace procedure p_test is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');
end;
/
```

---

Running `runme.bat` at the OS command prompt results in this:

```
M:\>runme

M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @run_proc.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sri Lip 13 11:28:00 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

M:\>
```

Apparently, it *works*. Now, you may play around with different settings (echo, feedback, whatever), but - generally, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the SQL/SQL*Plus commands to an separate script:

myscript.sql:

```
set heading off
set feedback off
BEGIN
AML.DO_ACCOUNT_AML() ;
COMMIT

END;
/
```

And the leave that batch script to handle only the control flow:

myscript.bat:

```
echo off
sqlplus username/password@databasename @myscript.sql
!
```